# adding clickable image links to jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i show some images with the simple script shown below. how can i make the images clickable?

thank you!

```
$(function() {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();     
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: JScript? You mean jQuery? `:)`

Comment: Please remove the JScript tag, JScript != Javascript

Comment: @M28: I have retagged the question

Comment: For some reason the retag button wasn't showing up for me, anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').click(function() {
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: I have two images switching between each other. What i want is when the browser clicks "only" the second image, the clicking takes him to a new site. Could you write for me the entire script doing this trick including my original script?

Comment: Check the code now. You can of course chain the lines 2 and 3.

Comment: there is no http://? let us say i want to go to google.com, how do i include that?

Comment: OK. It works. Thanks a lot! However, I want it to open in new window, what do i do? like _blank attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you're going to need to decide what to **do** when an image is clicked, but:

```
  $('.fadein').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
    var clickedImg = this;
    // your code
  });
```

Comment: I have two images switching between each other. What i want is when the browser clicks "only" the second image, the clicking takes him to a new site. Could you write for me the entire script doing this trick including my original script?

Comment: Well I can update that - next time, it would be a good idea to include such details in your original question!